# Get first post from facebook for the user

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am creating a webapp that requires to read all status of the user he has posted till date and take some decision based on that. I am new to FQL. I am using below query:

```
SELECT status_id,time,message FROM status WHERE uid=me() AND 
source = 0 ORDER BY status_id ASC LIMIT 1
```

**What I already know?**

I have read few post related to my question and come to know that FQL returns posts from last 30 days only.

**What my problem is?**

I need to read the first ever status update done by user and so on but my query returns the status update which is done recently. I have tried it with my own Facebook account and its not fetching my first status update.

Comment: FQL isn't supported anymore, is there a reason you cannot use the Graph API?

Comment: @TinyGiant, I am new to this and found that FQL is similar to sql so I went for that. I have just started, so can you give me a link to some blog, tutorial. I am going through https://developers.facebook.com/ but its time consuming to understand Graph API quickly. btw funny username :D

Comment: Facebook's documentation is horrible at best, unfortunately the most useful information I can point you to is [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api), [the graph explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) and [the Stack Overflow tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfacebook-graph-api%5d%20is%3aq). I suggest doing some digging around and some experimenting with query parameters.